# What are some good "dad jokes"?

Tags: parents

Dad jokes are a type of joke that can (typically) only be told by a dad that is often perceived as embarrassingly bad (especially by the children of said dad). Dad jokes often, but not necessarily, involve some form of pun or wordplay.

A well known example of a dad joke would be:

> Child: I'm hungry!
>
> Dad: Hi Hungry, I'm dad.

While these jokes often evoke groans rather than laughter form children, they may be remembered fondly years later.

**What are some dad jokes that you have used successfully (or that have successfully been used on you)?**

Comment: And knowing these jokes makes us better parents because we embarras our children less? ... Anyway, this sounds like fun, let's not close this question, ok? :)

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/dadjokes may be relevant.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't consider this a joke but a good way to let the child know that this is not a proper way to speak. Former president Chirac famously had the same reaction after being called an unflattering epithet by a protester.

Comment: Sorry, but this is considered a "list question", and is off-topic for our site. Generally, if you're asking for a list of answers, where every answer can be completely different, but equally valid, it's not a good fit for our site.  This is specifically addressed in our help center, under [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”"

Comment: @Beofett could you join me in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting)?

Comment: @Dariusz There is currently a [meta discussion](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/q/723/11472) going on about this question staying open or not.

Comment: When she was little, I asked my daughter if she was hungry.  She looked up at me as if though I were born stupid and said, "No, I'm $childs_name." I teased her about that for years.

Answer (score 6):

I like to joke, but my 2 year old is too young for word-play Dad jokes. If slapstick silliness counts as a "Dad joke" then this is my favourite.

A "tickly spider" (actually my hand) creeps towards my daughter. I point it out and pretend to be worried. She starts to snigger as it gets close then it jumps on her causing a lot of giggling.

This doesn't work if she's tired or upset. So it's one way to work out if she wants attention or comfort.

In the second round the tickly spider turns on Daddy, who tries to look genuinely frightened, maybe falling off his seat. That's usually even funnier.

Comment: Now, my bad sense of humor thought when I read "actually my hand"... "Oh, good b/c 'tickly spiders' are more dangerous than 'daddy longlegs'!" lol.

Answer (score 6):

One of my personal favorites goes as follows: (Best used when driving by a city and you have a good overview of it. <sub>even better at a lookout point when having a meaningful moment together.</sub>)

> Dad: There are going to be thousands of people in Dover<sub>1</sub> tonight
>
> Me: Why?
>
> Dad: Because they live there.

<sub>1: My dad didn't say Dover, since I didn't grow up in England but rather Belgium, I doubt many people know Leuven though.</sub>

Comment: Fine town, Leuven. Lived there for 5 years. Never been to Dover.

Comment: Been Dover? I try not to unless necessary.